# About Sorting String In C++

Tags: c++, sorting

How can I do a stable sort of words in a string based only on the length of each word, so the longest words come first, and the shortest words at the end (but words of the same length retain their original order relative to each other)?

For example: 
Input:

```
sj a sa df r e w f d s a v c x z sd fd
```

Resulting output:

```
sj sa df sd fd a r e w f d s a v c x z
```

Comment: show us some code You`ve tried to do it

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand what you are saying. English is a hard language! Please ask someone more fluent than you to write the question.

Comment: Maybe try by giving an example.

Comment: I tried in C but in many forum or blog i got some tips and code.. they did it pair

Comment: Are you sorting characters inside a string or a vector of `std::string`?

Comment: Are you defining an element as one or more characters, separated by spaces? If so, do you want to re-arrange them so that the longer elements appear before the shorter ones, but you don't care if the length is the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to split the string into a collection of string then sort that collection and concatenate the result into a string again: you can use a custom comparator using the size of the string and feed it to `std::stable_sort` with the collection of strings to sort:

```
// Your original string
std::string your_string = "sj a sa df r e w f d s a v c x z sd fd";

// Split the string
std::istringstream iss(your_string);
std::vector<std::string> words{
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>()
};

// Stable sort by size
std::stable_sort(std::begin(words), std::end(words), [](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) {
    return lhs.size() > rhs.size();
});

// Merge the results back with spaces
std::ostringstream oss;
std::copy(
    std::begin(words), std::end(words),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(oss, " ")
);
your_string = oss.str();
```

Of course, this algorithm is not optimal. To avoid much of the computation, you could store directly a vector of strings and work with that instead of storing your words in a space-separated string. Among the suboptimals things: we copy many things from the original string while some things could probably be moved to and from the `words` vector (not sure). The mere fact that we strip the spaces to add them back is a clear hint that we're doing more than we could.

Also, note that the final string will have an additional trailing space that you can choose to remove with `pop_back`.

Comment: Rather than an explicit copy, I'd just initialize `words` from the stream: std::vector<std::string> words { std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), std::istream_iterator<std::string>() };`

Comment: @JerryCoffin Oh right, it makes things simpler. Thanks :)